# Reduce too big gap between C3 widget and surrounding text in Rmarkdown

Tags: r, r-markdown, c3.js, htmlwidgets

I want to include an gauge plot in my rmarkdown document using `library(c3)`. However, the gap is too big:

````
---
title: "Gauge"
output: html_document
---

# Gauge

Too big gap to the gauge:

```{r, echo = FALSE, message = FALSE}
library(c3)
data.frame(x = 50) %>%
   c3() %>%
   c3_gauge()
```
This is fine.
````

This results in this output:

[image: Gauge]

The whitespace above the gauge and the text is too big. How can I reduce it? Playing with `height/width` in `c3` did not help.

---

After the answer of @Daniel I played with several options and contrary to my first attempts, setting the ehitgh did do the trick (as did changing the fig height) - weired:

````
---
title: "Gauge"
output: html_document
---

# Gauge

Too big gap to the gauge:

```{r, echo = FALSE, message = FALSE}
library(c3)
data.frame(x = 50) %>%
   c3() %>%
   c3_gauge()
```
This is fine.

# Gauge fig.height = 2, height = 200

Too big gap to the gauge:

```{r, echo = FALSE, message = FALSE, fig.height=2}
library(c3)
data.frame(x = 50) %>%
   c3(height = 200) %>%
   c3_gauge()
```
This is fine.

# Gauge height = 200

Too big gap to the gauge:

```{r, echo = FALSE, message = FALSE}
library(c3)
data.frame(x = 50) %>%
   c3(height = 200) %>%
   c3_gauge()
```
This is fine.

# Gauge fig.height = 2

Too big gap to the gauge:

```{r, echo = FALSE, message = FALSE, fig.height=2}
library(c3)
data.frame(x = 50) %>%
   c3() %>%
   c3_gauge()
```
This is fine.
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know CSS you can try adding it in your Rmarkdown, just like an R chunk, but I was not able to get the right attribute tag from the inspect element, due to limited webdev knowledge. Maybe this has to do with the padding of the webpage

```
{css echo=FALSE}
.c3-chart {
  height: 200px; 
}
```

Also I made another edit and maybe it can help you, I hope.

````
---
title: "Gauge"
output: html_document
---

# Gauge

Too big gap to the gauge:

```{r, echo = FALSE, message = FALSE, fig.height=2}
library(c3)
data.frame(x = 50) %>%
   c3() %>%
   c3_gauge()
```
This is fine.
````

This made the white space smaller, but also made the text smaller, but maybe you can play with this and see if you can find a solution with the `fig.height` options in the R chunk

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this was also exactly my first idea. But looking at the elements it seems to me that the white space comes from c3 and is not due to the HTML. It's all `svg` tags, so I do not know which controls the padding. Most liekly it is a slot in the `C3` JS which I need to set via the R interface.

Comment: I added to my answer, see if this can help you

Comment: Thanks this does the trick. Strangely enought, now setting solely the height in `c3` seems to render just fine too. Dunno what happened, but thanks a lot for helping.